# How to configure ldap to resolve host names?

Tags: linux, ldap, hosts

I'm new to LDAP and I already configured accounts with LDAP so I can login on few computers with LDAP.

Now I would like to add some host names to LDAP. In `/etc/nsswitch.conf` I changed:

```
hosts:          files dns ldap
```

But I have no idea how to add anything to LDAP database so it could resolve some names. I tried google but I couldn't find anything helpful.

On example, how to add this:

```
192.168.1.1    node1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I already figured it out with help of `migrationtools` (ubuntu package).

First, create file `add_hosts.ldif`:

```
dn: ou=Hosts,dc=example,dc=net
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Hosts
```

Load it with:

```
ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=example,dc=net -W -f add_hosts.ldif
```

Above steps should be done only once.

Then create file `node1_host.ldif`:

```
dn: cn=node1,ou=Hosts,dc=example,dc=net
objectClass: top
objectClass: ipHost
objectClass: device
ipHostNumber: 192.168.1.1
cn: node1
cn: n1
```

I added second `cn` so it can resolve both `node1` and `n1`.
If you want to add another host, just create another file `node2_host.ldif` and load it into LDAP.